# Kendo Tab Strip Event for AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-tabstrip

I have following Tab

```
<div kendo-tab-strip  k-options="tabStripOptions">
            <ul>
                <li class="k-state-active">First tab</li>
                <li>Second tab</li>
            </ul>

            <div style="padding: 1em">
                This is the first tab
            </div>

            <div style="padding: 1em">
                This is the second tab
            </div>
        </div>
```

In My Controller I have wrote following code for Event :

```
$scope.tabStripOptions = {
            select: function (e) {
                console.log("Selected: " + e.item.innerText);
            },
            activate: function (e) {
                console.log("Activated: " + e.item.innerText);
            },
            show: function (e) {
                console.log("Shown: " + e.item.innerText);
            },
            contentLoad: function (e) {
                console.log("Content loaded in " + e.item.innerText);
            },
            error: function (e) {
                console.log("Loading failed with " + e.xhr.statusText + " " + e.xhr.status);
            }
        };
```

But No Tab is Creation but if I remove `k-options="tabStripOptions"` from `<div>` then Tab is coming but no event.